# An invalid character was found in text content.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

> An invalid character was found in text content.'.
>   Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
>   sp_xml_removedocument: The value supplied for parameter number 1 is invalid.

Below is the xml that i am generating.

```
<NewDataSet>
<ControlManagementItems><ControlId>74</ControlId><Value>wqeqe</Value></ControlManagementItems>
<ControlManagementItems><ControlId>76</ControlId><Value>Yes</Value></ControlManagementItems>
<ControlManagementItems><ControlId>78</ControlId><Value>Consumer Core $100 infinite  – Nov 2010</Value></ControlManagementItems>
<ControlManagementItems><ControlId>108</ControlId><Value>Samsung Galaxy S 16GB</Value></ControlManagementItems>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: You are missing sample C#/SQL code that actually causes exception. There is nothing wrong with XML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line "Consumer Core $100 infinite – Nov 2010" has an invalid ASCII character which is "–"

Comment: If you still want to use the same "–" character, then provide an XML tag with appropriate encoding

Comment: How can i do that? Please help.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> Add this line to the top

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post. But hopefully what I did helps someone else. I have changed the datatype to NVARCHAR because it allows many more font families than VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you solved this issue or not, but i had the same problem couple days ago. Because of some turkish characters.

Here is my solution :

Put the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` line on top of my broken xml file and change the turkish characters with notepad++. After putting the top line, **notepad++** shows the problematic turkish characters (like xOD), then i replaced them with the utf ones.